# How to increase the memory if I get this error TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: errors, miktex, memory

I am using the following codes to input DNA sequences from fasta format (177 sequences with 1140 base pair long) Using texshade package but I had the following error:

my system is: Windows 7 (64 bit)

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].
```

Dose anyone know how to resolve this problem and your help would be appreciated

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{texshade}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=.5cm, right=.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{texshade}Concerted-evolution-2.fas}
\shadingmode{similar}

\threshold[80]{50}

\showruler{1}{top}
\hidenumbering


\end{texshade}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know next to nothing about the `texshade` package, but you have an unmatched brace in line 6; it should be `\begin{texshade}{Concerted-evolution-2.fas}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/texshade/texshade.pdf) (pdf) of `texshade` states on page 13 that a `! TeX capacity exceeded` error might orccur. It also gives instructions on how to increasse the capacity. The only difference to your error is that it does not talk about `save size`, but about `main memory size` or `stack size`.

The principle of increasing the capacity should also work here. Instructions for increasing the `save_size` for TeXlive can be found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134599/60839) answer.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I have read the manual and I could not find this file (miktex.ini) in the Config folder on my system.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use MikTex, so I can only guess. [The documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/runtimeparams.html) says to run `initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex` on the command line to open the configuration file. If that works, try to find the line that starts with `save_size` and increase it to 80000. Otherwise add a new line at the end: `save_size=80000`.