# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]

Tags: errors, pdftex, spreadtab

I am working in a large spreadsheet using `spreadtab` package.
The spreadsheet is basically a billing list with individual prices; quantities and total price for all items.
Even with a high number of items, I had no problems with the spreadsheet, however, the list has now ~400 and I am getting the error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]`.

I tried to follow a previous suggestion from [TeX capacity exceeded (save size)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134597/tex-capacity-exceeded-save-size?rq=1), and changed the `texmf.cnf` file in `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\web2c` without success.

There is a way to overcome this problem?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass
[
10pt,
a4paper                                                     % paper size
]
{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{lrrr}}
\toprule
@                   &   0   &   0   &           \\
\midrule
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
@   Item A          &   2   &   26  &   [-2,0]*[-1,0]   \\
\midrule
365.5*26*4/7                &       &   [1,0]   &   sum(d2:[0,-1]) \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally it indicates faulty code if save size overflows. See e..g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134597/tex-capacity-exceeded-save-size

Comment: Try to isolate the parts of your code which produce the error, and post a minimal example.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I added the code. If I delete some rows (~50), it works.

Comment: Your example code compiles fine for me, it just takes ages. I tested with `pdflatex` from TeXLive2016.

Comment: The sample code runs fine for me, also.  However, if I double the number of rows then it breaks as OP says.  Even `lualatex` gives up with a Tex capacity exceeded error (save size).  These limits can be increased.

Comment: Yup, even the larger version compiles fine with lualatex when I increase the save size.  For pdflatex, main memory size is the constraint.

Comment: @JPi lualatex solved the problem for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's usually a coding error that leads to this message, I think in this case it's legitimate.

I wasn't able to grok the implementation immediately, but in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/spreadtab/spreadtab_doc_en.pdf) of the `spreadtab` package we read:

> ... `spreadtab` proceeds in 3 main stages before `\begin{<table environment>}`sees the table:
>
> - first, it reads the body of the table, divides it in lines and cells, and in each cell, seeks a possible formula;
> - then, it computes the formulas in the cells, taking care for each to previously calculate all the dependent cells. The calculations are done by the fp package;
> - finally, it is necessary to rebuild the table, replacing each formula by its numerical calculated value and handing over to the environment name specified by the user.

It sounds like this process defines one, possibly more, macro *per cell* in the spreadsheet.  Since there is a limit to the number of macros TeX can hold, there is a limit to the spreadsheet's size.

It sounds like switching engines solved your problem for now.  But my instinct would be to use the right tool for the job.  And LaTeX is just not a spreadsheet program.  You could use Excel or a free, open-source alternative for a spreadsheet, LaTeX to format reports, and python as glue between them.  There are python libraries for parsing spreadsheet files (CSV, but also others) so you can probably do this quickly.

Comment: It is at least a bug in fp that let the save stack grow. See the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459626/increase-save-size-on-texlive-on-windows#comment1155971_459626