# Increase save_size on texlive on windows

Tags: texlive, windows, memory

While compiling a short file with spreadtab, I got the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
```

Based on other answers in this site, I ran on a Windows shell:

```
kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf
```

and got:

```
c:/texlive/2018/texmf.cnf
c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

I opened the first file and added the line:

```
save_size  = 200000
```

and then re-compiled the file, but still got the same error message.

What should I do to increase the save size?

EDIT: here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{spreadtab}  
\begin{document}
\STautoround{3}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{l|llllllllll}}
& 7 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\\
\STcopy{>,v}{1 - 2 * exp(2*ln(!b!1)-2*ln(!c!1))} 
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\\
& & & & & & & & & &
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

When I remove one or two rows, it compiles fine (and fills all cells with -2.92).
But when I add the rows back, I get the error.

Comment: Are you sure that the capacity is really the problem and that this is not just a symptom of some problem in the code? (just asking because very often this error is caused by an infinite loop or similar)

Comment: I would say 99% of documents that use more than 1000 save stack slots have a coding error that means that the save stack usage grows unnecessarily (usually local and global assignments to the same csname)

Comment: @samcarter not 100% sure, but when I compile the spreadtab table with 5 rows it works fine, and when I add a 6th row it breaks.

Comment: what happens with luatex?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: as  guessed above the code (fp package) is doing  `\global\let\FP@tmp=\FP@tmp%` which means that its save stack usage will basically grow very rapidly and fill your stack whatever size it is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so is this a bug in fp? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I had a quick look at fp but it uses this idiom everywhere (several dozen instances) so it would need a bit of a rewrite. it may be easier to patch spreadtab to use a different implementation of arithmetic eg l3fp, but I don't know that code., finally it should work to increase the stack and rebuild the formats, but depending on the size of your real example you may reach some hard limit, as the code will use unreasonable amounts of stack space.

Comment: One possibility is not to use standalone - it puts an additional group around the content. With article your example compiles. Beside this I think it is not only fp, spreadtab itself and xstring seems to contain dubious assigments too.