# Bibtex hash size exceeded

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texlive, texlive-2017

I am trying to compile my manuscript. I am using a large bibtex [database](http://cryptobib.di.ens.fr/) that contains conference papers, in addition to my custom bib file.Also I am using the [CCS template](https://github.com/acmccs/format/blob/master/ccs-template.tex), as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{mybibliography,abbrev3,crypto}
```

But when I compile my tex, I am getting the following errors, and the reference list does not show up:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
The style file: ACM-Reference-Format.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: appendix.aux
Database file #1: mybibliography.bib
Database file #2: abbrev3.bib
Database file #3: crypto.bib
Sorry---you've exceeded BibTeX's hash size 100000
Aborted at line 291526 of file crypto.bib
(That was a fatal error)

Process exited with error(s)
```

However, if I break the bib files into 3 separate lines, it compiles (with some warnings) but I am getting my references displayed 3 times...

```
\bibliography{mybibliography}
\bibliography{abbrev3}
\bibliography{crypto}
```

Is there any solution for that? I have tried looking on how to increase the Bibtex hash size but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Use `bibtex8` (instead of `bibtex`) with the option `--wolfgang` or set `--mstring` to some (very) high value.

Comment: Tried both, `--wolfgang` didn't work as well with bibtex8, I also tried `--mstring 1000000` and I got error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000]. {ISC:KanSulHaq07}`

Comment: You can set `save_size` to a higher value by editing `texmf.cnf` (which you can find with `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`) →  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134597/tex-capacity-exceeded-save-size

Comment: Nope.. Added `save_size  = 100000` to `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`  but still same error.

Comment: Well, then you have to slim down the bibliography: http://cryptobib.di.ens.fr/custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't use this humongous [database](http://cryptobib.di.ens.fr/), instead copy the relevant entries to a new and slimmer  `.bib`-file

---

Since `crypto.bib` is rather huge (21M), you have to use `bibtex8` and set `--mstrings` to a rather high value. I tried `bibtex8 --mstrings 700000` and it kind of worked, i.e. `bibtex8` still threw lots of warnings and errors.

I compiled a small test document with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{abbrev3,crypto}

\end{document}
```

Which produced a neat PDF of 4534 pages:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, while bibtex8 seems to work with warnings as you said, when I run `pdflatex` after I'm getting lots of `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active` errors and finally
`! Undefined control sequence.`. My tex works fine otherwise. I also tried to manually download the database from their website as you suggested but their script seems to be broken..

Comment: @Panos you have to ignore the error. The database too big and buggy to use. You'd be better off, copying the relevant entries to an new `.bib`-file

Comment: @Panos - If you get lots of `Underfull \vbox` warnings (not *errors*), try issuing the instruction `\sloppy` before `\bibliography`.

Comment: @Panos The `Undefined control sequence`-errors are caused by math in titles of papers  (like: *"The art gallery problem is $\exists\mathbb{R}$-complete"*). You need to load `amsmath` and `amsfonts` to get rid of the errors.

Comment: Ok I loaded `amsmath` and `amsfonts`, am still getting error: `Undefined control sequence. ...` and `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].` Added `\sloppy` as well before `\bibliography` but same errors again. These are now under MikTex. (the original error was under Texlive2017/2018) I could just select the relevant articles from the database but then it misses its point (having the same database used for all manuscripts).

Comment: Ok I eventually found out that there were a couple of entries in the database that had some weird stuff in brackets and they were responsible for the undefined control sequence errors. Problem solved. Thanks!