# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000] appeared in large data

Tags: errors

I use Datatool and get data from excel file.

My tex file is longe.

With 200 excel rows: compile done,

With 600 excel rows: error “TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000]”

Compiled in 2 computer (windows 10, 16 Gb RAM, CPU core i5, CPU core i7)

My Latex: Windows 10, Texlive 2019, Texmaker 5.0.3

Please help, how can i fix error “save size=50000”?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499349/a-bug-to-center-a-tabular (see the duplicate topic, the answer is there)

Comment: Look at section **2.6.4 Problems with TEX’s Memory Capacitie** of the manual of pgfplots.

Comment: Normally it indicates faulty code if save size overflows. See e..g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134597/tex-capacity-exceeded-save-size

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. thank for your help. i found file texmf.cnf in C:\texlive\2019 and edit save_size  = 100000  like image: https://imgur.com/jZlR7Ei. But same error. ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].<to be read again>\pgfmath@@onquick }

Comment: yes, as I wrote: normally you get it from faulty code and to solve it you will have to correct the code. Without an example it is not possible to say more.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. Thanks. Fauty code can work with 200 rows data of datatool but 500 rows don't work? Right logic with latex? Thanks

Comment: yes that can happen. It could also be that one of your 300 additional data rows contain something that latex doesn't like.

Comment: Thank so much, i will check each 200 data rows and try other solution if all data are correct.